# By changing a slot to scoped slot, it no longer appears on this.$slots and this.$scopedslots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a parent component and a child component (which has a vuetify table).

I am trying to make certain columns display chips from the parent component. I've run into a weird problem which I'm not sure what is the matter.

Parent Page: (Parent page is more complicated than this which is why I have taken out the table into another component so I can reuse it in combination with other stuff elsewhere)

```
        <simple-table
          v-if="!loading"
          :tableData="tableData"
          :loading="loading"
          :headers="headers"
          @search=""
          :selected.sync="selected"
          itemKey="groupName"
        >
          <template v-slot:userDatasetAccess="">
            <v-chip  color="red" dark>test</v-chip>
          </template>
        </simple-table>
```

When the code is like above, I can see test in a chip appearing in the UserDatasetAccessColumn

Child Page

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="tableData"
        :search="search"
        :loading="loading"
        loading-text="Loading... Please Wait"
        show-select
        :item-key="itemKey"
        v-model="selected"
        @input="$emit('update:selected',selected)"
      >
          <template v-slot:[getSlot(slot)]="{ item }" v-for="(_, slot) in $slots">
            <slot :item="item" :name="slot"></slot>
          </template>
      </v-data-table>


  methods: {
    getSlot(slot) {
      return `item.${slot}`
    }
  },
```

However, when I change the parent to:

```
          <template v-slot:userDatasetAccess="item">
            <v-chip  color="red" dark>{{item.userDatasetAccess}}</v-chip>
          </template>
```

It no longer works.
I've console logged this.$slots and this.$scopedslots and they become empty.

So my question is: Why is it that when I do v-slot:userDatasetAccess="" vs v-slot:userDatasetAccess="item", it no longer appears as part of $slots and $scopedslots.

Is there a better way to access the columns via slots from the parent?

Comment: It should be `$scopedSlots`. See https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-architecture-frcnl.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should use `item` like this: `<template v-slot:userDatasetAccess="{ item }">`

Comment: @User28 yes I have done $scopedslots

Comment: @m3hdi ive done that too

Comment: @limjix It must be `$scopedSlots` not `$scopedslots`. Did my example work for you?

Comment: can you make a pen for it so we could see more details ?